# How to know which connection closed in "use of closed network connection" error

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I'm proxying TCP connections in Go using `io.Copy`

```
_, err := io.Copy(src, dst)
if err != nil {
   log.Println(err)
}
```

and one connection closes therefore sending this error:

```
readfrom tcp 171.31.80.49:10000->88.39.116.204:56210: use of closed network connection
```

How do I know which network connection closed? i.e. `171.31.80.49:10000` or `88.39.116.204:56210`.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? What are `src` and `dst`?

Can you annotate the error before returning it to get some info? Like with `fmt.Errorf("error copying data from x and Y: %w", err)`.

Comment: @maxm both `src` and `dst` are `net.Conn`s. How should I log them as if you log the by default it is not human readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TCP connection is a pair of IP and port pairs. In your case, the connection is `171.31.80.49:10000->88.39.116.204:56210`. It is the connection, and it is closed. There is no connection `171.31.80.49:10000` or `88.39.116.204:56210`.

There are two connections in your example: `src` and `dst` (you misnamed them, by the way: https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy). If your question is which connection is getting closed, then, according to the error message, it's `dst` (which is supposed to be named `src`).

Why? Because the message says: `readfrom ...`, the error occurs when the `io.Copy` is reading from the Reader, which in our case is `dst`.

Comment: Wow! Great answer! I am very grateful.